# Persisting Full Data Binding POJO to Database

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I have converted `JSON` response to `POJO`, following the concept of `Full data binding`.

`POJO` looks like this

```html
public class User {
    
    public Name _name;
    
    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("_name") Name _name,){
      this._name=_name;
    }

    public static final class Name {
      public String _first;
      public Gender _gender;
      
      @JsonCreator
      public Name(@JsonProperty("_first") String _first,@JsonProperty("_gender") Gender _gender){
        this._first = _first;
        this._gender = _gender;
      }

      public static final class Gender {
        public String age;
        public Gender(@JsonProperty("age") String age){
          this.age=age;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Now I need to persist this `POJO`, but I am not sure how should I do that efficiently, I have consider using `Hibernate` but I am unaware how to proceed.

How fields would be annotated in case I use Hibernate, since this is a complex `POJO`.

Is there a way I could use `JDBC` ? or any simpler and efficient way to achieve persistence with this kind of `POJO`.

Looking for a detail answer or an example or something that would clear my concept.

Thanks